# Script adding line break in middle of string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

The script is adding a line break right after the curly braces while writing both strings right after the username.  I would think this is because of my source text file has encoding in it adding the breaks but as far as I can tell it does not.  Am I misunderstanding how write works?  Something simple I'm missing.  Been looking at this too long and need a new set of eyes.

```
users_list = []

users = input("File of User's ")

user_file = open(users  + '.txt', 'r')

for i in user_file:
    users_list.append(i)

sql_file = open('sql.txt', 'w')

sql_file.write("SELECT MACHINE.NAME AS SYSTEM_NAME, SYSTEM_DESCRIPTION, 
MACHINE.IP, MACHINE.MAC, MACHINE.ID as TOPIC_ID FROM MACHINE WHERE 
((MACHINE.USER_NAME = '{}') OR ".format(users_list[0]))

for i in users_list:
    sql_file.write("(MACHINE.USER_NAME = '{}')".format(i))
    sql_file.write(" OR ")
```

The output of the file looks like this:

```
SELECT MACHINE.NAME AS SYSTEM_NAME, SYSTEM_DESCRIPTION, MACHINE.IP, MACHINE.MAC, MACHINE.ID as TOPIC_ID FROM MACHINE WHERE ((MACHINE.USER_NAME = 'hnelson
') OR (MACHINE.USER_NAME = 'hnelson
') OR (MACHINE.USER_NAME = 'snery
') OR (MACHINE.USER_NAME = 'jherman
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if that's your output, I'd expect it to end in an OR, you also appear to be missing at least one bracket

Comment: Lines of a file end in `\n`. If you want to get rid of them, you need to `.strip()` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your line 7 and 8

```
for i in user_file:
    users_list.append(i)
```

to

```
for i in user_file:
    users_list.append(i.strip())
```

and it should work as expected.

It is because `i` is a line from `user_file` and it ends with `\n`. `i.strip()` removes the trailing newline.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!